# how to implement a changing user input

Tags: python, input

I have a Python 3.8 program where user inputs number of weeks for data to be entered (i.e 2 weeks) then from that number they need to enter number of customers each day of the week for each week.

```
n = int(input(" Enter number of customers for " ???? " of " ####))
```

where `????` needs to rotate through `Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday`
and
where `####` needs to rotate through number of weeks entered (i.e after the input line has rotated through each day of the week for week 1 then needs to rotate through each day for week 2 etc.

Comment: Can you share that program - or part of it - so someone can help you with your code?

Comment: what you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok next time show your work, but I understand your pain. So what I did and what you need to do is create a list of weeks and a list of days in a week. Then you will iterate thought the weeks and every week you will iterate thought the days in a week. Then you can just use concatenation to join your variables into the input.
Here is the code you can clean it up:

```
DaysOfWeek = ['Monday','Tuesday']
weeks = ['w1','w2']
for week in weeks:
    for days in DaysOfWeek:
        n = int(input(" Enter number of customers for "+str(days)+" of "+str(week)))
```

Comment: Thank for help in the right direction, this works perfectly with a few minor mods to get to do exactly what i need. thanks again Air Stalk3r.